# UISlider ValueChanged action not working

Tags: ios, swift

I want to calculate a number in real-time with UISlider, this is my method:

```
@IBAction func HPsliderValueChanged(_ sender: CustomUISlider) {

    calculator.HPPercentage = Double(HPSlider.value)
    HPValue.text = String(Int(HPSlider.value * 100)) + " %"
    resultLabel.text = String(calculator.calculate())
}
```

Both the `HPValue` label and `resultLabel` are expected to change value when user swipes on slider, however, now only `HPValue` label changes, the `resultLabel` doesn't work.

`calculator` is not nil, here's its code:

```
class TurretDiveCalculator {

var hero: Heroes = .taka
var build = [DefenseItems](repeatElement(DefenseItems(name: "Empty Item", index: 0, price: 0, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "EmptyItem")), count: 6))
var HPPercentage: Double = 0

func calculate() -> Int {
    let baseHP = hero.HPLow + (hero.HPHigh - hero.HPLow) / 12 * Double(hero.level)
    let baseDefense = hero.armorLow + (hero.armorHigh - hero.armorLow) / 12 * Double(hero.level) + hero.shieldLow + (hero.shieldHigh - hero.shieldLow) / 12 * Double(hero.level)

    var buildHP = 0.0
    var buildDefense = 0.0
    for item in build {
        buildDefense += item.armor
        buildDefense += item.shield
        buildHP += item.HP
    }

    let fullHP = baseHP + buildHP
    var HP = fullHP
    let defense = baseDefense + buildDefense
    var numberOfShots = 0

    while HP > 0 {
        let perShotDamageRaw: Double = 330 + Double(numberOfShots) * 0.09 * fullHP
        let mitigatedDamage: Double = 0.09 * perShotDamageRaw + 0.9 * perShotDamageRaw / (100 + defense) * 100

        HP -= mitigatedDamage
        numberOfShots += 1
    }

    return numberOfShots
}

}
```

How do I get `resultLabel`'s value to change in real-time, too?

Comment: Just a few things for you to try. 1) Can you set the value of `resultLabel.text` to a "normal" string in your method? (for instance, if you set the value to `resultLabel.text = "Hello World"`, does that work then?) 2) What does your `calculate` function return? Try adding a `print(numberOfShots)` just before the `return` to see what the outcome of `calculate` is.

Comment: @pbodsk yeah `resultLabel` can change but `calculate` doesn't return anything

Comment: OK...now we know where to look then :). When you say "doesn't return anything", do you mean that it returns 0 or does it not return anything at all (cause it should right? I mean, you've declared a method that is expected to return an `Int`)

Comment: @pbodsk it prints nothing in the console, so it returns nothing at all

Comment: interesting :) Can you try setting a breakpoint in the method and stepping through it, just to see a) if the method is actually invoked. b) where things go wrong.

Comment: @pbodsk sorry about the result that it prints nothing at all, I forgot to remove the comment on that line :) now it prints 6 when it's called, but the value of the label still doesn't change

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127768/discussion-between-bright-future-and-pbodsk).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As can be seen in the chat, we managed to find the problem.

This answer is just some general debugging tips and tricks when a problem like this arises.

The original problem was:

> now only HPValue label changes, the resultLabel doesn't work.

Lets find out where the problem is. Here's the code:

```
resultLabel.text = String(calculator.calculate())
```

Two things can go wrong here:

1. The `resultLabel` is not properly wired. To see if that is the case, try setting the value to a plain ol' string and see if you can see that. I you can, well, the textfield is wired properly.
2. The `calculate()` method returns an unexpected value. Try verifying what the method returns by adding a `print` statement just before the `return`

And as you can see in the chat, once we'd isolated where the problem occurred it was easier for @bright-future to track down the issue.

Hope this helps anybody when they are trying to debug a problem :)

Comment: Great tips to everybody !